# Extend an existing drive a drive with windows storage spaces

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, storage-spaces

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 with a 500GB SSD drive that is storage for a mysql database.  I am running out of room and purchased a 1TB SSD drive.  What I would like to do is use Windows Storage Spaces to just extend onto this 1tb drive so I will have 1.5tb.

The only options I see is "Storage Pools" in the Server Manager.  Is this the same as storage spaces?  And within storage pools, the only option is to create a pool using unformatted disks.

From what I understand, Storage Spaces should allow me to add multiple drives, even if they are being used.  Is this not the case?  Am I perhaps not even using the actual storage spaces?

Answer (score 1):

In order to take advantage of the "Storage Pool", I believe both of the disks has to be unallocated space. Meaning it can't be used to combined to increase the space of the existing disk

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff399600.aspx

You can add the existing disk to the same drive as a mount point to increase the space to the same drive. However, it doesn't help the situation if it's one SQL Database that's growing larger than the space on that disk.

Comment: Would copying the data to a 3rd disk, then combining the two SSD together into one pool work?  As in, would it allow the sql database to span the two drives?

Comment: Yes, if you can move the data to the 3rd disk, then move it back to the new storage pool once it is created. In order to create the storage pool, you would need to clear the data within. Here's additional information on steps needed to create storage pool "https://www.petri.com/create-storage-pool-on-windows-server-2012"